# CTRL-V mapped to paste instead block visual mode in Vim on Elementary OS (linux)

Tags: linux, vim, editor

I have just started using Vim on a Linux distribution -- Elementary OS. In Vim, `CTRL-V` appears to be mapped to `paste` instead of taking me to block visual mode. How do I reverse this? I'm pretty sure I didn't configure vim to behave this way and from what I've read so far this should only happen in MS Windows.

Edit: Contents of `.vimrc`

```
" 1. Pathogen (plugins autoloader)
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on


" 2. Documentor
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php inoremap <buffer> <C-P> :call PhpDoc()<CR>
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php nnoremap <buffer> <C-P> :call PhpDoc()<CR>
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php vnoremap <buffer> <C-P> :call PhpDocRange()<CR>

let g:pdv_cfg_Package = 'FPP Labs Package'
let g:pdv_cfg_Author = 'Gboyega Dada <gboyega@fpplabs.com>'
let g:pdv_cfg_ClassTags = ["package","author","version"]


" 3. Syntastic
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0


" 4. Tab stops
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for this site, since it is not a question about programming. You could post in the specific [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: Please show the contents of `.vimrc`.

Comment: @Renzo, Developer tools are on-topic for SO, although it's not a bad idea to suggest that faster help can be had at the other SE site.

Comment: First thing I would try is disabling all plugins, and then adding them in one by one to see if any of them are causing the issue. The second thing I'd do is look at the global `vimrc` file.

Comment: Ok, disabled all plugins temporarily with `vim --noplugins ...` (and removed my `.vimrc` file temporarily too) `CTRL-V` still maps to `paste`.

Comment: Please show us `vim --version`, or at least the relevant parts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not really a vim Issue.

Elementary OS uses their own terminal called *Pantheon Terminal*, which uses CTRL+C/CTRL+V for copying/pasting. This prevents the shortcut from being passed on to vim.

You should change the terminal to some other application, or change this behavior in the terminal settings.

Here's some blog with more info that I just found:

http://lmelinux.net/2014/12/06/ctrlc-will-copy-text-clipboard-elementarys-terminal/

The part that is interesting for you is:

> Elementary developers are also aware that some people will not be happy with this change that’s why there will be a new gsettings key at org.pantheon.terminal.natural-copy-paste where one can disable this behavior.

Comment: Thought as much. I also see what they are trying to do. On Mac OS you can do `Command-C` and `Command-V` in Terminal (and in Vim) without interfering with `visual block mode` because there are separate `CTRL` keys. On a PC you're stuck with just `CTRL` keys :(

Comment: So the answer is `dconf write /org/pantheon/terminal/settings/natural-copy-paste false` ;)

Comment: `gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false` in Elementary 5.0 Juno

Comment: @MartínColl right, and that should be notified in the answer :)